# Got a terrible letter from my PI instead of a promised good letter. Is not including it a lot better than incluidng it? Should I work for a while?

Tags: phd, recommendation-letter, stem

I posted earlier about my situation. [I'm changing PhD programs, and I got a terrible recomendation letter form my advisor. I found out by accident. What do I do now? I'm shocked](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/202465/im-changing-phd-programs-and-i-got-a-terrible-recomendation-letter-form-my-adv/202527#202527)

To recap: I'm a PhD student in a STEM field, and I'm transferring because I was fired from my lab despite good academic and research performance. My PI promised me a decent/good letter, but I was warned by another professor that it's actually a pretty bad letter that sounds really negative and dismissive.

I cannot post the letter for evaluation obviously, but it starts off by saying that he no longer supports me as a PhD student in his group despite me having passed candidacy. Then, he mentions that I am definitely smart and that a lot of professors (course instructors) even told him they are impressed with my grasp of the field; and the positive side ends on him saying I worked hard and put in long hours in the lab, and that we are still working on a paper. But then, he lists a lot of negatives (like me being a lone wolf, unorganized, and that my presentations are terrible). The negative part is a bit longer. The worst thing is however, the fact that in the end, he says that he has reservations, but that he thinks I deserve a chance to try my luck getting a PhD somewhere. That sounds negative, right?

I know the situation is pretty grim either way, but... Is my only choice to hope for a miracle? Should it actually significantly increase my chances if I use a good letter from another professor instead? Or is it my negative perception (that is shared by the professor who warned me apparently) and this letter is actually not that bad? Some people told me not using my former PI's letter is an even bigger red flag than this letter. Or maybe, it's better to work for a while in my field, and then, apply to PhD programs?

Comment: I know this is not an answer to your question, but the things you mentioned like "bad presentations", "lone wolf", "poor organisation" are all skills that can be improved so don't feel bad about yourself.

Comment: I recommend simplifying the question to "In math, how much will this letter hurt my application?" To me what you describe seems pretty normal -- certainly the fact that he "fired" you but still recommends you requires a detailed explanation, and so he listed both your pros and cons. But you said in your other post that his letter was so negative that a random person felt compelled to give you a heads-up. So getting a clear verdict from people who know your field about how damning this letter is seems like the first step.

Answer (score 0):

Oof, that's rough. Sorry you're advisor shafted you like that.

You're stuck between a rock and a hard place - not sending the letter is going to read as "the letter was so bad I couldn't send it". Which, while true, is not the impression you want to make. Obviously sending the letter isn't ideal either. My experience in academia is that great letters are good, good letters are okay, and okay letters are a red flag on their own. Bad letters can be a death sentence.

So what to do? My gut reaction is to try to stay in the program with a different advisor. I don't know if that's realistic for your situation but if there are others that have worked with you, and don't share your advisor's opinion, you might be able to find a new home. If you can't stay at that program, this would be the time to leverage whatever network you have - other professors, researchers, whoever you have interacted with thus far who might be able to help. Basically you need someone to either take you in themselves or vouch for you.

Alternatively you can try to get ahead of the problem and explain your difficulties in whatever personal statement you're submitting with your application. This is probably the time to be frank about the issues you had, frame them in a more flattering light, and focus on your strengths - including the strengths your advisor mentions.

Whether or not you *keep* sending out the letter is up to you though. I think either option is equally bad (for slightly different reasons), but which you choose depends on how you put together your application. It might be better to not send the letter, explain you had a falling out with your advisor and see where that gets you.

Example 1: Send the letter (because at least your advisor is providing *some* support for you getting another position). Focus on how you have recognized your weaknesses, addressed them, and include a letter that is *much* more positive. Ideally have that writer address the same things you do - i.e., VroomVroom123 had a,b,c problems but has improved in x,y,z ways. This option is rough because obviously the letter says what it says.

Example 2: Don't send the letter. Focus on the same things, but control the narrative a bit more. Include the most positive letter(s) you can kind. Know that people will assume the worst in this case.

Comment: Thank you. Another re letter writer briefly mentioned one of the mitigating circumstances in his letter. Do you think that would make the situation a bit better if I don't send my advisor's letter?

Comment: I don't think I will hurt. But you really need someone who understands the situation to help you make these decisions and put together a coherent application.